# Como setar um texto com base no id do EditText e não no nome do EditText?

Tags: android

quando vou setar um texto em um EditText eu faço assim.

```
EditText edit = new EditText(this);
edit.setId(0+4);
edit.setText("Meu Texto");
```

Porém eu presisava setar o texto pelo id porque no meu caso tenho vários editText chamados "edit". Eles tem o mesmo nome, porém diferentes ids. Isso é possível? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Julgo ter uma resposta mas, para ter a certeza, necessitava de ver como está o seu código. Não estou a ver como pode ter mais de uma variável chamada `edit`

Comment: eu estou criando dinamicamente os editext's, eu criou esse Edittext dentro de um "for", o que diferencia os editTexts são os ids, que eu fiz essa gambiarra para ir incrementando e ter ids diferentes.

Comment: Esses *EditText* são associados a alguma *View/Layout*?

Comment: Sim, há um LinearLayout, estou fazendo tudo na mãe, sem usar nada em xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se os *EditText* estão associados a uma *View/Layout* pode obter a referência a cada um deles através do *Id* usando:

```
EditText edit = (EditText)view.findViewById(id);
```

`view` é o *LinearLayout* onde estão inseridos os *EditText*

Comment: Obrigado ramaral, era exatamente o que eu precisava!